# What are the differences between these two strings?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

When inserting an event in google-calendar-api using Golang I can get my event to work when I hard code the date 
'DateTime: "2019-04-11T14:00:00",'

but not when I generated it from variables 
'DateTime: evtEndDate + "T" + evtEndTime,'

I can't see any difference but the API does

Here I printf the constructed variable and it's type followed by the hardcoded variable and it's type. They look identical

```
2019-04-11T06:00:00     string
2019-04-11T06:00:00     string
2019-04-11T14:00:00     string
2019-04-11T14:00:00     string
2019/04/11 12:48:17 Unable to create event. googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for: Invalid format: "2019-04-11T14:00:00", invalid
exit status 1
```

The go code I'm using is:

```
event := &calendar.Event{
    Summary:     data.schShift + " - Test Event",
    Location:    "Canada",
    Description: "Test event added by Go utility",
    Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{

        // This doesn't work
        DateTime: evtStartDate + "T" + evtStartTime,

        // This works (when unREM'd
        // DateTime: "2019-04-11T06:00:00",
        TimeZone: "America/Toronto",
    },
    End: &calendar.EventDateTime{

        // This doesn't work
        DateTime: evtEndDate + "T" + evtEndTime,

        // This works (when unREM'd
        // DateTime: "2019-04-11T14:00:00",
        TimeZone: "America/Toronto",
    },
}
evtStartDate = evtStartDate + "T" + evtStartTime
fmt.Printf("%v\t%T\n", evtStartDate, evtStartDate)
fmt.Printf("%v\t%T\n", event.Start.DateTime, event.Start.DateTime)
evtEndDate = evtEndDate + "T" + evtEndTime
fmt.Printf("%v\t%T\n", evtEndDate, evtEndDate)
fmt.Printf("%v\t%T\n", event.End.DateTime, event.End.DateTime)
```

I expected the variable to be accepted as it seems to be the same type

Comment: It seems like what the API is expecting is a string in the RFC3339 format. Try using `time_object_here.Format(time.RFC3339)`

Comment: SOLVED: 
I moved the equation out of the struct setup and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the equation out of the stuct setup and it worked. Makes sense although I was sure that was how I'd started.

```
    evtStartDate = evtStartDate + "T" + evtStartTime
    evtEndDate = evtEndDate + "T" + evtEndTime


    event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary:     data.schShift + " - Test Event",
        Location:    "Canada",
        Description: "Test event added by Go utility",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: evtStartDate,
            TimeZone: "America/Toronto",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: evtEndDate,
            TimeZone: "America/Toronto",
        },
    }
```